# Get info from URL and place it into HTML

Tags: html, url

After a user submits a form, they are redirected to a page with this url:

example.com?name=John

How can I put 'John' into a div on the page, so that the page displays 'Thank you John' ?

Comment: based on the tags in your question, you can't use html to do that. you will need php or jquery for that. PHP: `echo "Thank you " . $_POST['name'];` or jquery (a whole lot more code)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Unfortunately, I will need to use javascript/jquery for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i did understand you correctly, but if i did, you could get the value from query string and then change the div content just using vanilla JS.

Like this:

```js
const name = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('name') ?? "John";
const greeting = document.getElementById("greeting")

if(typeof(name) !== 'undefined' && name !== null){
  greeting.innerHTML = `Thank you ${name}`
  greeting.style.visibility = "visible"
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div id="greeting" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
</html>
```

Ignore the **?? John** is to have something to show without an actual query string.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it. Thank you!

Comment: How can I hide a div if a parameter from the url is not present?

Comment: Sure, no problem. Updated my answer to reflect that behavior.